# How to verify valid session and session data in ColdFusion .cfc page?

Tags: session, authentication, coldfusion, cfc, coldfusion-2016

I have been developing single page application that runs on ColdFusion 2016. I already developed login page and now I would like to develop security for each Ajax call that is sent to `.cfc` page. There is many functions in this file and my main focus is to check if user Session exists and to check if Logged in User has `Admin` or `User` access. There is set of functions that should be accessed only with Admin access. The other functions are available for both User and Admin. Here is example of my Session scope that keeps all user info after successfully passed authentication:

```
<cfset var appStruct = structNew()>
<cfset structInsert(appStruct, "SysAdmin", SystemAdmin, true)>
<cfset structInsert(appStruct, "UserName", UserName, true)>
<cfset structInsert(appStruct, "AccountID", AccountID, true)>
<cfset structInsert(appStruct, "Email", Email, true)>
<cfset SESSION.AccountInfo = appStruct>
```

Code above is executed once user is logged in, then I have check on the top of my `.cfc` file:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfif structKeyExists(SESSION, "AccountInfo")>
        <cfset LoggedAccountID = SESSION.AccountInfo.AccountID>
        <cfset isAdmin = SESSION.AccountInfo.SysAdmin EQ 1 ? true : false>
    <cfelse>
        <cfabort>
    </cfif>

    /* Here I have many functions that are used by Users and Administrators. */
</cfcomponent>
```

Then on top of this in each `cffunction` I always check if `AccountInfo` session exists and if Admin access is set to true for Administrator functions. Example of one of the functions that is only accessed by Administrators:

```
<cffunction name="findAccount" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="JSON">
    <cfargument name="sessionID" type="string" required="yes" default="fakeSession">        
    <cfargument name="frmFindaccount_search" type="string" required="yes">
    <cfset var fnResults = structNew()>
    <cfset var runProcess = true>

    <cfif !isAdmin OR !structKeyExists(SESSION, "sessionid") OR (SESSION.sessionid NEQ arguments.sessionID) OR !structKeyExists(VARIABLES, "LoggedAccountID")>
        <cfset var fnResults.status = "400">
        <cfset var fnResults.message = "Credentials Error!">
        <cfreturn fnResults>
        <cfabort>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

I'm wondering if all steps above are enough to protect unauthorized users to access any functions/data in my system? Also the other questions is about this block of the code:

```
<cfif !isAdmin OR !structKeyExists(SESSION, "sessionid") OR (SESSION.sessionid NEQ arguments.sessionID) OR !structKeyExists(VARIABLES, "LoggedAccountID")>
    <cfset var fnResults.status = "400">
    <cfset var fnResults.message = "Credentials Error!">
    <cfreturn fnResults>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

I have this on the top of each `cffunction` in my `.cfc`(some functions do not have `!isAdmin`). I'm wondering if this can be only placed on the top of my `.cfc` instead of having this in each function? If anyone see any code that can be improved or have any advise please let me know. This is my first individual project and I'm trying to follow standards and prevent security threads.

Comment: I would add the !!isAdmin block into a function of its own, and call it inside each other function. This will make things more modular. Also, remove the duplication of the method local variable 'var' declarations. 'var foo = 1' should only be declared once, immediately after the 'arguments' block, and then just reference without the 'var', thereafter. Or you could just use the inbuilt 'local' scope, like 'local.foo = 1', and then you can remove 'var' altogether. As for your business logic, it is hard to tell, without more information, whether your login security is robust or not...

Comment: @CharlesRobertson I was thinking about creating function that would hold that code and then just making call to that function as needed. I was wondering if have to use `var` or  `local` every time in order for that variable to be local. So you thinkt hat declaring only once with var or local should be fine and apply to all other places in that function?

Comment: Watch out for `myurl.com/mypage.cfm?isAdmin=42`. The code you've shown _should_ deal with a simple injection like this, but unscoped variables (`isAdmin`) can do strange things.

Comment: @Shawn I just discussed with my lead about that, so doing something like this `<cfset variable.isAdmin = 1>` should take care of that. Correct? This way we specified the scope and ColdFusion would know that source should come from the global variable.

Comment: Also, you can significantly shorten and clean up your code by switching to cfscript and implicit struct/array syntax.

Comment: Yes, it should. Although you may not need another variable since you're already passing its source in the session.

Comment: @Shawn What do you mean by `you might not need another variable` ?

Comment: You may not need to bother creating `variables.isAdmin` when you can just reference `SESSION.AccountInfo.SysAdmin`. Plus, that would tie it a bit tighter to your session, so that if that session were deleted, expired, etc then your user would no longer be `isAdmin=true`.

Comment: @espresso_coffee - I think Charles was suggesting creating functions instead of using variables. Create an `isAdmin()` function that contains that logic and returns a `boolean`. If another function needs to know if the current user is an admin it just calls the function `<cfif isAdmin()> ... do stuff </cfif>`. No extra variables to carry around.

Comment: "declaring only once with var or local should be fine"  Yes. Though it won't break anything, you only need to declaring a variable in the `local` scope or with `var` once. Though as mentioned, I don't think you need a separate "isAdmin" variable. Encapsulating the logic in a function would be cleaner.